# Reindexing dataframes and joining columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given two DataFrames A and B which are the same length (number of rows) but have different integer indices. How do I add the columns of A to the columns of B but ignore the indices? (i.e. row 1 of A goes with row 1 of B regardless of the index value.)

If the index of A is non-consecutive integer index, how do I reindex A to be 1...n using consecutive integers? The index of be is a 1...n consecutive integer index.

Is it best practice to reindex A and then add columns from B to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the columns of two DataFrames using [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
```

To make the index consecutive integers you can use reset_index:

```
A.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Or, alternatively you can match the index of B to that of A using:

```
B.index = A.index
```

*What the "best" choice is here I think depends on the context/the meaning of the index.*